# How to quickly find GCD for a million numbers

Tags: python, list, greatest-common-divisor

I tried this:

```
from fractions import gcd
from functools import reduce

def solution(list):

     x = reduce(gcd, list)
     return x
```

but it's taking a long time

Comment: FWIW: `math.gcd`'s documentation says "Changed in version 3.9: Added support for an arbitrary number of arguments. Formerly, only two arguments were supported."

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Your solution does not look bad, but we would need more information about your problem before recommending a good solution. Do you know more about the size of your numbers? Do you know how many there could be?

Comment: I'm solving a problem in codewars and have to use 3.8

Comment: Using `math.gcd` instead of `fractions.gcd` would certainly help.

Comment: it starts from 800,000 until 2,000,000 and it's all random integers

Comment: The gcd of those numbers divides the smallest positive difference between any 2 of those numbers.

Comment: can you use multiprocessing or GPU processing?  btw, statistically the GCD will be 1 (99.99+%) , try return 1 and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you take one million *random* numbers between 800k and 2M, the probability that the GCD of them is greater than 1 is really really really low, try `return 1` and see what happens

Comment: it's unfortunately not working some GCD are 2 and some with other values like 6,630

Comment: i calculated it like 200k times and it was always 1... i guess those numbers aren't really random

Comment: you can easily make a random list with specific GCD py making random numbers then multiply it with that GCD and add them to the list you can even make a random list of numbers and use it as GCD so now you have random lists with different and random GCD and I think this is my case

Comment: you know what I think I'll give up I spent 3 days on this problem

Comment: @MohammedAli can you send me the link of the challenge?

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/52f677797c461daaf7000740/train/python

Comment: oh ok, the trick is to use lateral thinking

Comment: so what the idea?

Comment: just do the GCD on the first few hundreds of numbers